# Manually populating Mongodb field on document creation with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Following the Mongoose documentation, I was able to create two docs, but am unable to populate one with the other.

Despite manually setting the 'account' value to reference the other document, my database doesn't seem to create the relation.

Below is the code I've used:

```
UserAuth.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
  if (err) return done(err);

  if (user) {
    return done(null, false,
      { message: 'It appears that email address has already been used to sign up!' });
  }

  // Create the user account
  const newAccount = new UserAccount({
    name: {
      first: req.body.firstName,
      last: req.body.lastName,
    },
  });

  newAccount.save((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Create the user authentication
    const newAuth = new UserAuth({
      email,
      account: newAccount,
    });

    newAuth.password = newAuth.generateHash(password);

    newAuth.save((err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      return done(null, newAuth);
    });

    return done(null, newAccount);
  });
});
```

Collections:

User Auth

```
const UserAuthSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  account: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserAuth', UserAuthSchema);
```

User Account

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    first: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    last: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  team: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Team',
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    default: 'assets/default_user.png',
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: What you got in your collections?

Comment: I've added my collections to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the part:

```
// Create the user authentication
const newAuth = new UserAuth({
  email,
  account: newAccount,
});
```

should be:

```
// Create the user authentication
const newAuth = new UserAuth({
  email,
  account: newAccount._id,
});
```

And then, when you query the collection, you have to say which field should be populate, as shown in (Mongoose documentation)[http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html]

Ad please check that the types of the 2 linked fields are the same as mentioned in the documentation.